# How to save the same post in multiple blogs?

Tags: posts, blog, post-duplication

I would like to write my post in one of the my 3 blogs and the same post will be published in the other two blogs.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress plugin to publish to multiple remote WordPress blogs](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48553/wordpress-plugin-to-publish-to-multiple-remote-wordpress-blogs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook on `save_post` or `publish_post` hook in each post and publish in other blogs. You must use the function [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) to switch in other blog and then use `[wp_insert_post()][2]` to save a post inside this blog; do this for each blog.

Alternative is you search for a plugin, there doing this; like [Multi Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multi-post/). I don't know if is the right and a good plugin. I had use the search on www.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WordPress XMLRPC API.
http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API

Alternatively, take a look at the following plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/syndicate-out/installation/

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.